# Filtering the value of a subquery in the main query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have this following query:

```
select
*,
case when x in ('x','y','z',...) then 'X' end as value_x
from(
  select *,
  case when condition1 = true
       case
         when field2 == 'xxxx' then substr(field2, 0, 2)
         when field2 == 'yyyy' then substr(field2, 0, 2)
         when field2 == 'yxyx' then substr(field2, 0, 2)
         ...
       end
  end as value_x
 from table) as subquery;
```

When I do this, I end up getting 2 columns named `value_x`. Is there any way that I can filter `value_x` with the IN function without having to use it in every single case? There are a lot of cases, and it would really bloat up the query.

The query-subquery structure can't be changed, as there are dozens of those cases that use values from the subquery to create new columns, this is the first time that I have to update one of the columns coming from the subquery, and I can only use a `SELECT` statement.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Don't use `select *` in the outer query, select only the columns you want

Comment: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: Thing is, I want every column.

Comment: ...or give it a different name... so you'll have `value_x` and `value_y`.

Comment: The SQL Standard only offers you the `*` wildcard to select all columns. If you want anything different, you'll need to write the full comma-separated subset of columns.

Comment: I want every column, and I can't have value_x and value_y. There are hundreds of columns in the subquery, so if I had to write select (every single column except value_x) in the outer query, it'd get uglier than writing the IN statement for every value_x in the subquery.